# Unable to authenticate github account

Tags: github, atlassian-sourcetree

I have been trying to connect github to Sourcetree, however I'm facing an issue. I hope somebody could help me to figure this out.

Problem: unable to authenticate github account.
Hosting Service: GitHub
Preferred Protocol: HTTPS
Authentication: Personal Access Token

When 'Refresh Personal Access Token', the popup showed up and I typed my GitHub account's username under username and for password I pasted my personal access token.

This should work but it kepps saying 'login failed'

Does anyone know how to fix this? I'm using window pc.

Thank you in advance!

Again, this should connect GitHub and Sourcetree and enable repos to be cloned. But I got 'This is not a valid path/ URL when trying to clone the repos. I believe this is because it's not connected to my GitHub account.

Answer (score 0):

Double-check your [PAT (Personal Access Token)](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows)

For testing, create a new one which:

- should be a [classic one](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token#creating-a-personal-access-token-classic)
- with [scope repo](https://docs.github.com/en/apps/oauth-apps/building-oauth-apps/scopes-for-oauth-apps#available-scopes)

Note: you can check your token from your local workstation with:

- [`gh auth login --with-token < mytoken.txt`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_auth_login)
- [`gh auth status --show-token`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_auth_status)